# Problem with thebibliography command (number is not properly displayed)

Tags: bibliographies

Good time of the day!

Here is a LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}  

 \begin{document}

\section*{\centering Solutions}

\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt, label={\bfseries Problem \arabic*. }]

%---------------------------------
% Solution of Question #3

\item \mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt, label={\bfseries  (\alph*) }]
%-- 3a
\item \mbox{}   
\begin{description}[wide,  labelindent=1.5 em, leftmargin=1.5 em,labelsep=0.5 em ,align=left]
\item[$\bm{p=1.}$] 
Blah, Blah. 
\item[$\bm{p=\infty.}$] 
Blah, Blah.
\end{description}
%-- 3b 
\item 


\end{enumerate}


\end{enumerate}


%-------------------------------------------------
% The Bibliography 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem[Williams]{Williams} D. Williams, “Probability with Martingales,” Cambridge University Press, 1991.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

And here is a result:

[image: Result of compilation.]

How to correct display of numbers in bibliography?

Comment: The culprit is the missing text after the last `\item`.

Comment: ... But you may still want to remove the optional argument `[Williams]` from `\bibitem` so you only get a number instead of *Williams*: `\bibitem{Williams}`

Answer (score 1):

You have `\item` with no following text, but a blank line. This leaves LaTeX in a weird state as the corresponding label cannot be properly placed, so it ends up at the next `enumerate` environment, in this case the bibliography.

Solution: add `\mbox{}` after an `\item` that should have no text.